# Death of a black hole?

Tags: thermodynamics, black-holes, hawking-radiation

Is there a death of black holes?
If yes, what is the average lifetime of a black hole and what happens when a black hole dies?

Comment: There is a 'death' of black holes, but don't ask me on numbers. Black holes emit hawking radiation and thus loose mass until to the point where there is nothing left. At least up to my knowledge.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What happens when a black hole dies?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/90363/)

Comment: Thanks for the average lifespan of blackholes.